# How can I run my Node JS program the whole time

Tags: node.js

I wrote a WhatsApp bot using the [whatsapp-web.js](https://wwebjs.dev/guide/) module. My program only runs locally when I start it. But it should run 24/7. Can somebody help me? And how exactly do I have to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot to unpack here. I'm going to assume from the nature of your question that you're new to javascript and node development, so welcome!

Normally when we have an application that we want to have run "24/7" we have to deploy that application to a server, meaning a machine that lives somewhere on the internet. We do this because our local machines turn off, or are rebooted, or loose power. If we want something to run all the time, we'll typically put it on a machine that's running all the time.

There are a ton of options for this, "cloud computing" companies like AWS, Google GCP, Azure, DigitalOcean, Heroku, etc...

Since there are too many options to review each one, I'll describe how I like to do it.

I prefer to use a virtual machine deployed to a cloud provider. Most of them have a free tier where you can run a small, low powered machine for free. This should work fine for your chatbot.

Sign up for an account with, for example, Google, and create a free VM following their instructions. I recommend using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS for the VM image.

Next, you'll want to create a service unit file for systemd. Systemd is the thing that runs on linux that manages startup processes. A Unit file will look something like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Readings API Service
After=network.target

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment

Type=simple
User=app
WorkingDirectory=/home/app/deploy/packages/api
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node /home/app/deploy/packages/api/server.js
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

In the above, I've created a user named "app" on the linux system, and created a folder named "deploy" in that user's home directory. I'm telling systemd to start that program when the computer starts, and to restart it if there's an error and it accidentally crashes.

It's going to take a bit of research and studying to understand all this and how it works, but hopefully this will get you started.